# I want to get the urls of each home from the attribute content

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");


const url = "https://www.airbnb.co.in/s/Haridwar--Uttarakhand/homes?tab_id=home_tab&refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&flexible_trip_lengths%5B%5D=one_week&price_filter_input_type=0&price_filter_num_nights=5&l2_property_type_ids%5B%5D=1&search_type=autocomplete_click&query=Haridwar%2C%20Uttarakhand&place_id=ChIJyVfuuA5HCTkR8_VApnaRRE4&date_picker_type=calendar&source=structured_search_input_header";

async function scrapHomesPage(url)
{
    try
    {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    
    await page.goto(url);
    
    const html = await page.evaluate(()=> document.body.innerHTML);
    const $ =  cheerio.load(html); 
    
    const homes = $('[itemprop="url"]').map((i, element) => $(element).attr("content")).get();
    console.log(homes);
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        console.error(err);
    }
    
}

scrapHomesPage("https://www.airbnb.co.in/s/Haridwar--Uttarakhand/homes?tab_id=home_tab&refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&flexible_trip_lengths%5B%5D=one_week&price_filter_input_type=0&price_filter_num_nights=5&l2_property_type_ids%5B%5D=1&search_type=autocomplete_click&query=Haridwar%2C%20Uttarakhand&place_id=ChIJyVfuuA5HCTkR8_VApnaRRE4&date_picker_type=calendar&source=structured_search_input_header");
```

I tried to add everything I could to wait for the page to load all the contents. I tried wait for selectors etc. I am always getting an empty array instead I should get an array with all the links of each home listed on the Airbnb site for that particular location.

Comment: "I tried wait for selectors etc" -- this is the correct approach, so you might want to show that attempt..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see [any reason](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#using-a-separate-html-parser-with-puppeteer) to use Cheerio here. It's just another layer of indirection to get the data you want, involving an extra dependency, a whole second parse of the page and the potential for bugs when the page goes out of sync with the HTML snapshot you've created. If you *do* need to use it, you can use `page.content()` instead of `page.evaluate(() => document.body.innerHTML)`.

As for the main problem, you appear to be missing a call to `page.waitForSelector`:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^19.0.0

const url = "your url";

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  await page.waitForSelector('[itemprop="url"]');
  const content = await page.$$eval(
    '[itemprop="url"]',
    els => els.map(el => el.getAttribute("content"))
  );
  console.log(content);
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

Comment: At first thank you for helping me out. But I want to know that where is the problem in my code when I am trying to run my code it is returning me something like this.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vRfOdWwlx9AS3wILLAvlpeEL2DPaSTdY6DOg2vnN2UDtqJM9Ce_GmORjotPZBKy_eRhtBv-pCValpUd/pub

Comment: I just want to know that what is the problem with this code.

Comment: All I see in that link is a Cheerio object that doesn't tell me anything interesting, sorry.

Comment: yes and when I am using .get() in the end of map function it is returning me an empty array

Comment: Yes, because you didn't wait for anything as my answer explains.

Comment: It means that in the actual array no record is added and that's the problem with why it is not working and returning me an array with the same URLs  I needed.

Comment: I tried to do the same thing too the wait until method and also wait for selector still

Comment: Please edit your post to share that code as I [suggested awhile ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74704590/i-want-to-get-the-urls-of-each-home-from-the-attribute-content/74706775?noredirect=1#comment131854057_74704590). I can't help with code I can't see.

Comment: okay I am adding it.

Comment: You never returned `url` from your `map` function. If you're not familiar with Cheerio or Puppeteer, I'm going to repeat my suggestion to drop Cheerio. It seems to be adding to the confusion. You can select anything with Puppeteer. It's basically a superset of Cheerio. As I described in my article, unless you're an expert with a very specific need, the only reason to use Cheerio is if you're not using Puppeteer and are able to parse the static HTML from a simple HTTP response. Most people who are using the two together seem to be confused, as appears to be the case here.

Comment: I have edited my code you can check it now. The problem now I am facing is that sometimes it is returning all the URLs in the console and sometimes only the first URL but still the "homes" array is empty

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but I'm rolling it back since it invalidates my answer, which would make the post confusing for future visitors.

Comment: okay I got it where I was doing the mistake and I was confused but the only last thing I want to get that why sometimes I am getting all the URLs and why sometimes only one(first one).

Comment: I didn't experience that, but it's possible the selectors aren't all added in a single rerender, so you might want to use ```page.waitForFunction(`document.querySelectorAll('[itemprop="url"]').length > 10`)``` where `10` could be whatever minimum length you want to retrieve. You could additionally wait until there have been no changes to the length of this selector for some small length of time, or whatever other predicate you plan to block on.

Comment: but I can't use the `document` inside node.js directly right? it will show an error document not defined

Comment: No, you can't use `document` inside Node except through a simulation like JSDOM. But Puppeteer gives you access to the real deal: `await page.evaluate(() => document.doWhateverYouWant)`. You know this because you already used similar code to dump the HTML to a string. What are you trying to do where you need the document in Node? The document belongs in the browser and Puppeteer gives you a whole API of `evaluate()` functions to gain access to it. That's pretty much the whole point of Puppeteer, manipulating the document in real time.

Comment: Okay, I got it thank you so much for the help I hope I will complete my project with this and will achieve what I am trying to do. You did a great job by giving me your time and helping me out really appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Hey, I found where the problem was actually when the chromium browser loads if we don't wait there for the page to load completely and go to terminal it will show only one link but if we wait for the page to load completely it is working good. Thanks again for helping me out.

Comment: And yeah my code also worked using the cheerio too 